# Passing "data-" to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-ajax

I have the following code...

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="filterData" 
    data-filterString="@Model.LastName">Filter</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
$("button[id='filterData']").click(() => {
      var dataList = [];
      var filter = $(this).data("filterString");
      $("input[class='personRecord']").each(function() {
         dataList.push($(this).val());
      });
      var parameters = JSON.stringify({ "filterString": filter, "dataList":paymentList });
      $.ajax({
         url: "/Employee/FilterName",
         data: parameters,
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function () {
            alert("Success");
         }
      });
   });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SendAll(string filterString, List<string> dataList) {
    ...
}
```

However, the variable `filter` keeps returning "undefined". How do you pass custom data items, `data-filterString` in this case?

Comment: Check the html your generating - is it `data-filterString="..."` or `data-filterstring="..."` (all lowercase)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jQuery, you can only use lower case values for the [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method, even if your attributes are upper/mixed case. So you should write:

```
var filter = $(this).data("filterstring");
```

If you do use mixed case in your key, jQuery converts that to a dashed variable, so when you search for `filterString`, your attribute should be called `data-filter-string`.

```js
$(function() {
  console.log($('#test').data('filterstring'));
  console.log($('#test').data('filterString'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test" data-filterString="value1" data-filter-string="value2"></div>
```